# Recognise Receipt data Xamarin native

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, ocr, receipt

Anyone knows some good lib our some source code to implement a receipt recogniser in order to get the data from it like product name, total amount, date?

I want to implement this in iOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an Image of Receipt and you want to extract some predefined text out of that Image.

You can go with [Microsof't Cognitive Service (Computer Vision API)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/), which reads text from the Image. Check for the Price per Transaction [Here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) However, it may not be so accurate, but you should give it a try to check if it fulfills your purpose.

This requires some string operations to get the specific result and you need to consider lot of variants of the Receipt you may be using in your app.

Check Xamarin's Blog and Sample Code [Here](https://blog.xamarin.com/performing-ocr-for-ios-android-and-windows-with-microsoft-cognitive-services/).

**Note**: If your receipt can add a Barcode, containing all details you want to extract, it will be better solution rather than this string operations, I guess.

Comment: thanks MilanG I already tested that  but is not that accurate with our test images. The target receipts don't have barcode